# C# - Using DLL library

Tags: c#

I'm new to C#, and i'm making a basic audio player for a school project. I found the [nAudio](https://naudio.codeplex.com/) library, downloaded it and it comes as a DLL. I know enough C# to do the project, just never used a DLL library. :\

Comment: All libraries are dll's btw.

Comment: Did you add the dll too your References?

Comment: Yeah but some are installed by default to say, a system location where i can just do `Using` Whereas this i don't know what to do with it because I downloaded it, it's not already there.

Comment: References? I don't know what they are

Comment: Are you using visual studio or compiling with csc?

Comment: Put dll into your project folder where the other .cs files are located.   Then from menu Project : Add Existing item : Browse for dll.  Then at top of module : using NAudio;  There are a number of library that can be added by putting a period after NAudio.

Comment: @jdweng - I don't think you want `Project > Add > Existing Item`.   I think you want `Project > Add > Reference`.  Adding the .dll as an existing item will just include the .dll in the project without actually referencing it.

Answer (score 4):

Just add a reference to the dll in the project. In Visual Studio: Right Click Reference -> Add References (In the Solution Explorer) -> Browse to dll.

Comment: You say right click "reference" Where is that?

Comment: In visual studio. What IDE are you using?

Comment: You need to expland the solution to the project level via the solution explorer then you will see references.  https://www.google.com/imgres?imgurl=https%3A%2F%2Fi-msdn.sec.s-msft.com%2Fdynimg%2FIC816783.jpeg&imgrefurl=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Flibrary%2Fez524kew.aspx&docid=o1UEkUOgCJLt9M&tbnid=nYIUBO5qSHIunM%3A&vet=10ahUKEwiRsOL6t5_TAhVHrlQKHYZ9AGQQMwgcKAAwAA..i&w=370&h=364&safe=strict&bih=609&biw=1067&q=visual%20studio%20references&ved=0ahUKEwiRsOL6t5_TAhVHrlQKHYZ9AGQQMwgcKAAwAA&iact=mrc&uact=8

Comment: Nevermind, I found it now, didn't see you said in solution explorer.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to use nAudio in a C# project is through NuGet.

Right-click on the References node in Solution Explorer and pick Manage NuGet Packages. Search for nAudio in the NuGet management dialog on the Browse tab. Click it in the results on the left-hand side, then click Install on the right-hand side.

NuGet provides a convenient interface to manage your project's external dependencies, including keeping up-to-date with the latest releases.

Comment: Ah I see. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In order to use an external DLL in C#, you need to do two things:

- Include it in your project's binary folder.
- Reference all the "external" calls you are going to do to it.

Here is an example:

```
    [DllImport(@"dliboperations.dll")]
    private static extern void InitializeShapePredictor(string ShapePredictorFilename);

    [DllImport(@"dliboperations.dll")]
    private static extern int Detect(int Width, int Height, byte* pImage, int MaxFaces, FaceInfo* pFaceInfo);
```

In this code, you can see *DLLImport* is referencing the DLL file and is an attribute for the function declared below.

You have to declare all the functions you are going to call.

There are tools that automate that process in case you have many functions.

I recommend looking at the source of [Emgu CV](http://www.emgu.com) since they wrap all the OpenCV API.

Comment: This would only apply for unmanaged code... I don't see any indication that OP is referencing unmanged code.

Comment: True; when he asked about using an external DLL, I made that assumption since it's usually what people are looking for, otherwise it's very straightforward; but I should have checked the lib he was using.